# Why is the transition not working when I am adding the element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am creating an element each time when the function is called, but the transition is not always working. I wanted a message coming from the top of the screen but it is adding the element instantly without applying the transition. An HTML example is provided for you to try it. This is the Codepen link https://codepen.io/arijit1st/pen/YzBvMrP.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="d1" id="d1">

  <button class="b1" id="b1">Click here!</button>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
const d1 = document.getElementById("d1")
const b1 = document.getElementById("b1")
let bottomCount = 160
let d3IdCount = 3
let svgIdCount = 4
let messagesCount = 1
let d3ST1 = null
let d3ST2 = null
let d3ST3 = null
let d3AlreadyExists = false

async function errorMessageUI(message){

    const d3 = document.createElement("div")

    d3.classList.add("d3")
    d3.id = "d3"

    const d3Exists = document.querySelector(".d3")

if(d3Exists){

      messagesCount++
      bottomCount += 100
      d3IdCount += 1
      svgIdCount += 1
      d3AlreadyExists = true
}

else if(!d3Exists){
  messagesCount = 1
  bottomCount = 160
  d3IdCount = 3
  svgIdCount = 4
  d3AlreadyExists = false
}

  d3.id = `${d3IdCount}`

  d1.append(d3)

    d3.innerHTML = `${message} <p class="p3" id="p3">  ${messagesCount > 1? "x" : ''}${messagesCount > 1? messagesCount : ''} </p> <svg style="opacity: 60%" class="svg4" id="svg${svgIdCount}" width="8%" height="54%" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path class="path4" id="path4" d="m4.12 6.137 1.521-1.52 7 7-1.52 1.52z"/><path class="path4" id="path4" d="m4.12 11.61 7.001-7 1.52 1.52-7 7z"/></svg>`

    d3ST1 = setTimeout(() => {
      d3.style.transform = `translateY(${bottomCount}%)`
    }, 0)

d3ST2 = setTimeout(() => {


d3.style.transform = "translateY(-300%)"
clearTimeout(d3ST1)
clearTimeout(d3ST2)

}, 5000)

setTimeout(() => {
d3.remove()
}, 5201)

    const crossSVG = document.getElementById(`svg${svgIdCount}`)

    d3.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {

      crossSVG.style.opacity = "100%"

    })

    d3.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {

      crossSVG.style.opacity = "60%"

    })

    crossSVG.addEventListener('click', () =>{

      clearTimeout(d3ST1)
      clearTimeout(d3ST2)

      setTimeout(() => {
        d3.remove()
      }, 201)

      d3.style.transform = "translateY(-300%)"

    })
  }

b1.addEventListener("click", () => {

  errorMessageUI("hello")

})
```

CSS:

```
.d3{
position: absolute;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    transform: translateY(-300%);
    transition: transform 150ms ease !important;
    display: flex;
    background: rgba(239, 87, 87, 0.83);
    width: 20%;
    min-height: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-left: 4px solid #af0e0edb;
    color: #990e0e;
    font-size: 1.07rem;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}
```

I excepted that the transition will work always when an element is added, but the transition is not always working.

Comment: For me your code doesn't work at all. I get a syntax error.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thanks for commenting and letting me know, the syntax error is fixed and now can you help me solve the problem?

Comment: It's best if you could provide a running sample in Codepen. Your code does not have a HTML file so we don't know how you are using the logic. 
I added one myself, added script to it and invoked `errorMessageUI` method but it has a runtime error saying: "ReferenceError: d1 is not defined at errorMessageUI". 
@ArijitDey

Comment: @NimaOmrani Thanks a lot for commenting and I did what you told and added an HTML example. I also added the Codepen link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Proplem

You have set a timeout and the cleared it directly. That would, for most of the time, not call the function — especially the last one. It is specifically at...

```js
d3ST2 = setTimeout(() => {
  d3.style.transform = "translateY(-300%)"
  clearTimeout(d3ST1)
  clearTimeout(d3ST2)
}, 5000)
```

### Solution

You can weather call the function one last time at the end, or just delete the `clearTimeout()`. [This is a working Codepen.io example.](https://codepen.io/MKebsi/pen/jOdKRpZ)

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, it solved the problem but it is not solving the problem where I am creating the website.

Comment: If your code is not under NDA, then why don't you share it, on Github or Codepen. There have to be something with the production built you are working with.

Comment: Mohammed Alkebsi  I would like to give you the website's URL which I am creating, but I won't like to share it publicly because it is still developing. So is there any way I can you give the website's URL?